# blackberry phonegap + webworks fileupload not reliable

Tags: cordova

I have been using the default test sample that comes with cordova and one thing I have noticed is that the fileupload function works initially and then seems to just suddenly stop working with a connection error: 3

Any ways around this?

The same issue has been occuring with my other apps I'm trying to make with phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ditching PhoneGap and only use the WebWorks FileUploader extension.

You can find it here: https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/Smartphone/FileUploader